# Mongosh doesn't connect to remote replica set but always tries on localhost

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, replicaset

I have a weird issue while trying to connect to a remote Mongo replica set.

This is my setup:

- on a remote machine I have three instances of MongoDB running on different ports, each belonging to the same `replocal` replica Set.
- the remote MongoDB is configured to bindIp `172.31.32.81,127.0.0.1` (both external and internal IPs)

From my local machine (running MacOS Ventura) i can connect to a single instance, but not to the cluster.

When I try to connect to the cluster (either via `mongosh`, or via Mongo Compass or even Studio 3T) I have the same error: it seems I am using a wrong syntax and the client tries to connect *always* to localhost, where of course I have no MongoDB running.

Here is a sample:

**connecting to single instance, primary**

```bash
$ mongosh "mongodb://172.31.32.81:27017"        
Current Mongosh Log ID: 649b09bca15bc473c95db139
Connecting to:          mongodb://172.31.32.81:27017/?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
Using MongoDB:          6.0.6
Using Mongosh:          1.10.1

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

------
   The server generated these startup warnings when booting
   ...(edited out , not relevant)...
------

replocal [direct: secondary] test>
```

as you can see I have the expected prompt from the remote MongoDB

**connect to replica set**

```bash
$ mongosh "mongodb://172.31.32.81:27017,172.31.32.81:27018,172.31.32.81:27019?replicaSet=replocal&readPreference=secondaryPreferred"   
Current Mongosh Log ID: 649b096a40719e3e693048bd
Connecting to:          mongodb://172.31.32.81:27017,172.31.32.81:27018,172.31.32.81:27019/?replicaSet=replocal&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Why is it trying to connect to localhost (aka 127.0.0.1)?

Now comes the interesting part: if I change the port of the first server to something other than 27017 I got of course an error, since no service is listening on that port, but the error is related to the correct IP, and not 127.0.0.1:

```bash
$ mongosh "mongodb://172.31.32.81:27016,172.31.32.81:27018,172.31.32.81:27019?replicaSet=replocal&readPreference=secondaryPreferred"  
Current Mongosh Log ID: 649b0d86045a207db47e25f2
Connecting to:          mongodb://172.31.32.81:27016,172.31.32.81:27018,172.31.32.81:27019/?replicaSet=replocal&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.32.81:27016
```

Am I using the wrong connection string?
It seems that the porto 27017 always assumes 127.0.0.1, disregarding the specified IP address.
I have tried with hostnames, the result is the same.

Thanks for any help,
best regards

Comment: How does your your replica set look like? What is the output of `rs.conf()` and `rs.status()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to a replica set, the driver:

- uses the host in the connection string as a seed to make an initial connection.
- runs the isMaster or hello command on that initial connection to get the full list of host:port replica set members and their current status
- drops the initial connections
- connects to each of the members discovered in step #2
- during operations, automatically monitors all of the members, sending operations to the primary even if a different node becomes primary

MongoDB drivers use unified topology by default, which permits the driver to automatically detect if it is connecting to a standalone instance, replica set, or sharded cluster.

In your situation it would appear that the nodes were added to the replica set using "localhost" or a hostname that resolves to localhost, so when the client receives the list of host:ports contained in the replica set configuration, they are all different ports on localhost.

To resolve this situation you will need to reconfigure the replica set with hostnames that the client machine can resolve to the proper IP address.

Comment: Yes!! this was the issue, and after reading this answer it makes even sense. What I did was to drop the replica set and then recreate with the external IP addresses for each node. If the nodes were not on `localhost` initially, I could have changed the replica set host names for each node without much fuss, instead I followed this answer to delete the replica set with wrong hostnames https://serverfault.com/questions/424465/how-to-reset-mongodb-replica-set-settings

Answer (score 1):

Running all ReplicaSet members on the same host does not make much sense, unless for testing and development.

As far as I remember, there is an internal limitation in MongoDB. If you run several  members on the same host then **all** members must be configured as `localhost:<port>`.

Comment: Hello, yes I know, it's for testing and development. We have a separate production environment with 3 VM, each one hosting a Mongo instance. Regarding binding to localhost it's not what I want, because I want to access the Mongo replica set from another computer.

Comment: Then set `bindIpAll: true`, then you can access from other computers. Anyway, when you add members to replica set then use `localhost`.

Comment: I fear that's not the so simple when you have already created a replica set (see accepted answer) but of course it maybe correct when starting from an empty installation. But again,  adding members with `localhost` will prevent from connecting from a different server.

Comment: Yes, your are right, I just tested it. But reverting a replica set to standalone is easy. Restart the mongod without `replication.replSetName` (or without `--replSet` option) and drop the local database: `db.getSiblingDB("local").dropDatabase()`. Then you can run `rs.initiate(...)` from scratch.

Comment: That's precisely what I have done (not with your nonchalance :). Right now it's clear and it works.